# How to crawl links that are stored in database through Fast search server 2010 for sharepoint

Tags: database, sharepoint-2010, web-crawler, fastsearch

I am crawling one database table through Fast Search Server 2010 for Sharepoint, which has a column called "URLS". Every record of this column hold one url of one web page. Thus there are many URLs in the database table.

I want that while crawling the database, Crawler should also hit the links which are there in the table. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/  ?
With a simple search on the fast-search tag on that site I found this question, that is somewhat similar to yours: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/display-web-page-preview-with-fast-search-for-sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility I see is:

1. Create a custom BDC connector in a Visual studio project to crawl your database.
2. When you get the urls from the database, you do whatever you can in C# (in your connector) to get the information from the site of the url.
3. You expose the information you get from the url site with properties in your connector
4. The connector properties can be mapped to managed properties after that to access the information in your search.

Don't hesitate to ask if I'm not clear enough, or if you need examples.